# How did Charlie Chaplin accomplish the gear stunts in Modern Times?

Tags: film-techniques, effects, stunts, modern-times

How was the famous scene in which Chaplin goes into the machine accomplished? Did they actually build gears for Chaplin to rotate around?

Comment: Based on time the movie was made and how special effect were done, what make you think it's something different? (apart from famous matte painting roler skating scene)